# Error when using pgfplots and beamerposter

Tags: pgfplots, beamerposter

I'm trying to create a poster presentation using beamerposter, and it refuses to compile when I insert my pgfplots plot. I get the following error message

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\end #1->\csname end#1
                      \endcsname \@checkend {#1}\expandafter \endgroup \if@e...
l.18    \end{frame}
```

when I try to compile this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerposter}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {
    (0,  .28138392)
    (1, -.6979761)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, this code, where I've just removed the beamerposter package, works fine:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {
    (0,  .28138392)
    (1, -.6979761)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I'm running an up-to-date MikTex 2.9 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `block` environments need a title brace pair even there is no title. So practically you have removed the `block` environment not the only `beamerposter` package declaration.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Beamer complains about fonts without this
\usepackage{beamerposter}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Up-to-date pgfplots complain without this
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{} % Extra brace pair makes it compilable. 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {
    (0,  .28138392)
    (1, -.6979761)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```